# C# Working with Images - Resources or Imagepath

Tags: c#, image, resources, filepath

i am wondering, what's the best way of working with images in c#, in a wpf application.

Someone recommend to pass the path of the image to the application, and someone recommend to use resources.

In my current project i have a listview and whenever i click a button, a image will be added. I am working with a ObservableCollection and whenever i click a button, i add the path of the image to the collection.
So, whenever i start the application i run throug the folder with the images and collect the names in an array. This way i can create the complete path to the image. 
After that i use a method to shuffle the array values.

I don't know exactly how i can do that with resources, because i can't access the path of the files, but i can directly access the image.

What would you recommend, using the path or resources, and how would you handle it? What's about the performance?

I searched a lot but didn't find an answer for my "problem", maybe i used the wrong keywords...

Comment: I use always Resources, compact, pack together with the main app.

Answer (score 0):

For "After that I use a method to shuffle the array values." just use some prefix or similar to root through the resources and throw whatever you need into a collection and apply your shuffling there. All you really need to track is the name. Using Resources will be more space efficient and adds a bit more safety into things.